# Usage of "wilt away"

Tags: word-usage

I've just read the following sentence in a book:

> He wilted away from the spot.

As I understand, this sentence means that he go away from the place with a sad mood. Is that right?

In this case, the use of this verb is usual, I mean, can I use it when I'm writting or is it only a one-time metaphor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a metaphor but one that is not unusual.

A plant will wilt if it has insufficient water.  The drooping of the leaves and loss of stiffness in the stem.

Thus the metaphor, someone whose shoulders droop and spirits sag is said to wilt.  To wilt away indicates that the person walks off dejectedly.